# How can I assign id to subject input box in simple machines forum?

Tags: forum

I have installed the simple machines forum. For my requirement I need to change the subject input box.

Presently the subject input box has the following code

```
<input type="text" class="input_text" maxlength="80" size="80" tabindex="1" name="subject">
```

I want this to be changed like

```
<input type="text" id="subject" class="input_text" maxlength="80" size="80" tabindex="1" name="subject">
```

How can I do this? I browsed through many files in simple machines forum and couldn't find out. Anyone one simple machines forum please help me

Comment: Use Totalcommander in windows or grep in linux to find this string `name="subject"` that should tell you the template it's in.

Comment: Can you specify `my requirement` a little closer? Maybe there is another solution for it than the one you tried.

Comment: @Anagio Do you know that for a fact? (And if so, it'd be better to just provide the actual filename.) Many applications use helper libraries to build things like forms, and the responsible source will look nothing like what you're saying. See the source blocks on [this page](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc2.x-php5/examples/elements.php) for an example.

Comment: @Su' I provided a comment suggesting a method to find it. I now gave an answer using the same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using totalcommander in windows I searched for `name="subject"`

```
 <input type="text" name="subject"', $context['subject'] == '' ? '' : ' value="' . $context['subject'] . '"', ' tabindex="', $context['tabindex']++, '" size="80" maxlength="80" class="input_text" />
```

line number `202` in file `Post-template.php`